# Difficult vlookup formula using cell value and wildcards

Tags: excel, syntax-error, excel-formula, wildcard, vlookup

I am trying to pull data in Excel using vlookup, but I need to use a cell value and a wildcard.  I have tried all of the syntax I can think of with no luck.  The current formula is:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A640,OpenIPB!A:B,1,FALSE)), 0, VLOOKUP(A640,OpenIPB!A:B,2,FALSE))
```

The problem is the value in A640 is "102-2028" and the value in OpenIBP that I need it to match with is "102-2028 - RA# 131009-43"  Can anyone help me with this?  I'm sure there is a cleaner way to go about this, but I'm stuck.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a wildcard in `VLOOKUP`, just change lookup value to `A640&"*"`

You can simplify formula with `IFERROR` if you are using Excel 2007 or later, i.e.

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A640&"*",OpenIPB!A:B,2,FALSE),0)`